# How to create folders from a list of files by last modified date month wise c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, system.io.file

I want to create folders month wise from a list of files.

I tried below code.

```
var files = directory.GetFiles()
                  .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime.Month == date.Month -1);

             //create folder for the files (With MonthName)
             var year = files.Select(j => j.LastWriteTime.Year).FirstOrDefault();
             var month = files.Select(j => j.LastWriteTime.Month).FirstOrDefault();
             var newFolderPath = year.ToString() + month.ToString();

             var destinationDirec = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directory + newFolderPath);

             foreach (var f in files)
             {                 

               // var destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, destinationDirec);
                 var path = Path.Combine(destinationDirec.FullName, f.Name);

                 if (!File.Exists(path))
                 {
                     System.IO.File.Move(f.FullName, path);
                 }                  

             }
```

The above code gave the list of files for the last month. But I want create folders for the files which are older than the current month.
Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Do you want to sort all your files by the month and then place them to separate folders with appropriate names?

Comment: Find max and min dates and iterate for each month/year between them to create folders. Then, when writing, use existing `var year ...` and `var month` to get the actual destination. Detail will depend on the date range you expect.

Comment: @kote - Yes You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code. Maybe with some changes.

```
//Group files by month. Later you can skip some groups if needed
var fileGroups = directory.GetFiles()
    .GroupBy(file => file.LastWriteTime.Month);

foreach (var fileList in fileGroups)
{
    var year = fileList.First().LastWriteTime.Year;
    var month = fileList.First().LastWriteTime.Month;
    var newFolderPath = year.ToString() + month.ToString();
    var destinationDirec = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directory + newFolderPath);

    //move files
    foreach (var file in fileList)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(destinationDirec.FullName, file.Name);
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.File.Move(file.FullName, path);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it's worth to modify `GroupBy` condition if you have a lot of files from different years.
For example you can use this condition:
`GroupBy(file => (397 * file.LastWriteTime.Year) ^ file.LastWriteTime.Month)`

Answer (score 0):

This should help, build the fullNewDir value as you need it.

```
String fullSourceDir = "G:\\Tmp\\Test";     
foreach (var fullFileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(fullSourceDir)){
    DateTime lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(Path.Combine(fullSourceDir, fullFileName));
    String fullNewDir = Path.Combine(fullSourceDir, lastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm"));
    if (!Directory.Exists(fullNewDir)){
        Directory.CreateDirectory(fullNewDir);
    }
    String fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullFileName);
    System.IO.File.Move(fullFileName, Path.Combine(fullNewDir, fileName));
}
```